# How to fill vertical spaces between tiles in a grid system (Using CSS)

Tags: html, css, gridview

I am trying to arrange cards in a grid system. Here are the properties of a card

1. Fixed width (Say 150 px)
2. Variable height (Depending upon content)

I can write a simple JS code to arrange the cards in a grid without leaving any space but I am just wondering if CSS can do it for me.

Here is the [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/jopoyuba/1/edit?html,css,output).

[image]

I am trying to go for CSS based solution because that avoids running JS code for re-arranging the cards whenever window is resized So I think CSS based solution will be more efficient. But I am unable to fill the voids.

**TLDR: How to remove these empty spaces and shift the cards upwards using CSS ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can live with the vertical order of the cards, then CSS3 `column` could be of use to you here.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8M3rU/***

*CSS*:

1. Provide `column-count` on the container. (include vendor prefixes like -webkit- followed by the standard)
2. Remove `float` from the child elements, and make them `inline-block`

.

```
.container {
    ...
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2; /* the standard property after all prefixed ones */
}

.a, .b {
    display: inline-block;
    ..
}
```

**Edit**:

Making the child elements as `inline-block` prevents them breaking into columns. This the way `columns` work in CSS3.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

However, the correct way to avoid unintended column breaks on child block elements is to use `column-break-inside`.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8M3rU/1/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
.a, .b {
    ..
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Wow..This works..As I already mentioned in my answer I tried `css3 column-count` but I guess float and display properties were causing the issues. Can you please explain the reason and I will accept

Comment: That is because of the way columns work. They break block elements. But, the correct way is to use `column-break-inside: avoid;`.

Comment: @abhitalks Why should he remove `column-count` leaving only the prefixed properties ? I guess this is wrong (instead, it must be put after the prefixed properties, not before)...

Comment: @AndreaLigios: That was unintended. I quickly created the fiddle and I tend to keep only -webkit prefix to reduce the clutter (as I use Chorme). Thanks for pointing that out. Fixing it up..

Comment: Instead of pushing the lower containers up to take up the space, is there a way to pull the upper container down to grow longer?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to simply use two containers, and fill them separately?
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jopoyuba/7/edit)

Use two separate lists:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
```

And give them this styling:

```
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 155px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

Which you may change to make it look as though it is one container.

Comment: +1 That is a nice solution indeed but we have to write JS code to send different cards into different containers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `CSS3 column-count` property and the result looks something better.

Checkout this [JSBin Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/jopoyuba/6/edit?html,css,output). But **the problem is last card is getting clipped-off**.

Check out the following image....

[image]

I would still love to know a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to add the following to each block

```
.a, .b {
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Mozilla */
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;  /* Safari and Chrome */
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

This basically tells it not to break the items up to make the columns equal